# How to check for a table fields value uniqueness and if not uniq make it uniq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In order for my Rails 4 app to have vanity urls, I have a polymorphic Slug table (id, url). Then in my Article model I have the following to create the slug:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :slugs, as: :sluggable, dependent: :destroy
  after_save :create_slug

  def create_slug
      return if !url_changed? || url == slugs.last.try(:url)
      #re-use old slugs
      previous = slugs.where('lower(url) = ?', url.downcase)
      previous.delete_all
      slugs.create!(url: url)
  end
end
```

The @article.url is currently being set in the controller with:

```
@article.url = @article.title.parameterize
```

This works really well unless there is a conflict, meaning an article is being created with a title already in use. In that case Rails error's with:

> PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

I'm thinking I need `create_slug` to check first if the value exists, if not then create the slug however, if the value does exist, append a -1 or -2 etc... to the end of the URL until the URL is unique. Does this sound right? What's the best way to handle/code for this scenario?

Answer (score -1):

The old behavior was implemented in the special [module](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/sequentially_slugged.rb). But at the moment it has not been released yet. So, if you want to restore old behavior you can switch `friebdly_id` in your Gemfile on Github and add `sequentially_slugged` to the modules list.

If you don't want to move for any gems then, A simplest thing for you is use the below code for making the URL's better....

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{slug}"
end
```

You can update the method code and make urls what ever you want.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not using that gem. Is all that really nessesary?

Comment: Hey, If you are not using it then I would suggest to move into it. It will saves a lot time for you.